# ReactJS acquiring JSON data

Tags: json, reactjs

You can find my JSON [data on this link](https://emjayweb.github.io/portfolio/scripts/snippets.json). What I am having trouble doing is acquiring `article` data from React.

My code is below. I did not include the JSON get request code in my question as it's not entirely consequential. I used the jQuery $.getJSON method to replace the state of `fulldata` with the array. So assume that the data is fully there under `fulldata`.

```
getInitialState:function(){
    return { fulldata: {forthem:[ {articles: [] } ]}  }
},

viewer:function(){
    return (<ul>
            {this.state.fulldata.forthem[0].articles.map(function(makeit, o){
                return <li key={o}>{makeit.article}</li>})}
            </ul>)
},
```

What this existing code allows me to do is acquire the first set of articles under `emjayweb`. However, if I modify the code to `this.state.fulldata.forthem[1]` I cannot get the second set of `articles` under `cnn`. I get a `Cannot read property map of undefined` error.

Comment: I would recommend moving everything into smaller variables and functions for clarity and you can verify at every step in the debugger what's happening. try putting a `debugger` statement in the `viewer` function right before the `return`

Comment: Are you trying to display all the article list from `emjayweb` and `cnn` all at once or show a set of articles after an event like onClick?

Comment: @jpdelatorre this is all meant to be rendered on page load. I did not include my render function in this question. Essentially what I want is to show all articles for both, but I am having trouble displaying the one from `cnn` because changing my `[0]` to `[1]` to my map statement does not work.

Comment: Once I understand how to show the articles from `cnn` in my JSON file I plan on adding a for loop to my code to show all articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one... so instead of using an external loop for getting the data, we use array's `map` and `reduce` function.

```
    const articles = data.forthem.map(item =>
        item.articles.map(article => article)
    ).reduce((list, current) =>
        list.concat(current)
    );
```

Working example below...

```js
const data = {
    "forthem": [
        {
            "therefore": "emjayweb",
            "theresym": "emj",
            "articles": [
                {
                    "number": "1",
                    "article": "How to Strengthen Your Password",
                    "url": "",
                    "pubdate": ""
                }, {
                    "number": "2",
                    "article": "Second Article",
                    "url": "",
                    "pubdate": ""
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "therefore": "CNN",
            "theresym": "cnn",
            "articles": [
                {
                    "number": "3",
                    "article": "Work It",
                    "url": "",
                    "pubdate": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <h2>Articles</h2>
            <ul>
                {this.props.articles.map(item => <li key={item.number}>{item.article}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            articles: []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const articles = data.forthem.map(item =>
            item.articles.map(article => article)
        ).reduce((list, current) =>
            list.concat(current)
        );

        this.setState({ articles });
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>React Demo</h1>
            <MyComponent articles={this.state.articles}/>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```